# How do I set the path to a file I am trying to open to be opened while hosted instead of depending on localhost directories wtih ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I'm building a website that handles 2 files (simple ones like .txt) and I'm struggling to see how I can write the path in a way that it works when eventually I host the website.
Currently, I'm using this line of code just to make it work while I am working around it:

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\pinky\source\repos\PAP\PAP\files\filename.txt");
```

But when I try to change it for the following bit of code:

```
File.ReadAllLines("/files/filename.txt");
```

It stops working. And the strange thing is, it only stops working for the specific page I changed the path of the files.
If I try to debug it, it gives an error 404 and asks me if I have the path of the page right (which it is). What can I do to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, in your web site, you have the root, and then some folders.

And we assume that files is one of those folders.

Lesson #1:

When a user (or you) wants to use a URL, then of course URL's are

```
www.mywebsite/Files/dogs.png
```

So, keep in mind that say in HTML markup, a src etc. Then a path name is always assumed to be from the root of your site onwards.

However, despite the above CODE BEHIND still will ALWAYS STILL use a valid windows FULL PATHNAME to the file.

So, you use a built in function called server.MapPath

MapPath will take the web based url, and convert to a full internal windows path name.

So, your code would be like this:

```
       string strIntenalFileName = Server.MapPath("/files/data.txt");

        string MyText = File.ReadAllText(strIntenalFileName);

        TextBox1.Text = MyText;
```

So just keep in mind that say we want to set a image control to have a picture from above.

Well, then we do this:

```
        Image1.ImageUrl = "/files/dogs.png";
```

But, if you need in code behind to read the file, then we have to put above expression though Server.MapPath() to translate for code behind.

So, just remember WHEN dealing with web controls, HTML markup, the of course the URL and path name is web based. But, for code behind to directly interface and use the file, then code behind needs that "plane jane" and full legal windows path name.

So, for your example, wrap the string in Server.MapPath(" your web based path goes here").

you in effect can't really know the root path name of the web hosting server, but with above, you really don't care.

Often however, one does get "messed" up. Since for the above image, I shoved in the web based url for SCR. But, if I was to read the picture and say stream the picture bytes to the web control, then I would of course first convert/get a full windows path name.

The above is not really all that confusing, but keeping this "web url", "web markup" and that of direct file use in code behind is still a VERY good concept to keep alive in your mind when dealing with files.

Now, the above is a simple tip - but one that I wish was hammered home to me.

So:
web expresions, markup = web path name from web root.

code behind:

Still always MUST be a full plane jane windows file name!

So, in your case, to get the text file, we could (and you should try this), is type in this:

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try this as soon as I can and get back to you.